# How can I use an properties file inside JBOSS AS7 in Spring?

Tags: spring, jboss, jboss7.x

I want to use somthing like this:

```
//@PropertySource("classpath:myconfig.properties")
```

My config file is in the **deployments** folder.

Remember:JBOSS AS7!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case (in JB 7), I have the properties in an exploded war file under WEB-INF and they get picked up.  I assume that you meant that the war file/folder was in the deployments folder.
and I use Spring 4

Comment: and I use Spring 4